# Can I trigger my Html.ValidationMessageFor with jquery and have it display some string I define in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

If I have a validation tag in my asp.net mvc application for a text field called search, can I plug into it using jquery/javascript to get it to trigger if certain logic is performed? How would I do that?

It looks something like this

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchQuery", other stuff here, other)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor("SearchQuery")
```

Say I want to trigger the validation message to show if this occurs

```
$('form').submit( function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(e);
  var results = GetLocation();
  if (results) {
    this.submit();  
  } else {
    // trigger validation message and display "can't find results"
    }
});
```

Please note that I don't think I need to validate here, I just want to show a message where the validation message would be if I did validate

Comment: What is `Html.Validate()` Is this your own extension method?

Comment: maybe the syntax is incorrect, but this is the built in validate helper for asp.net mvc. I want to throw this validation if some logic condition is true and give it a specific string to display.

Comment: maybe its @Html.ValidationMessageFor

Comment: Yes its `ValidationMessageFor()` and if you have client side validation enabled and included the relevant scripts, its all handled out of the box.

Comment: I do and it's working for validation checks like the "IsRequired" attribute but what I want to do is give it my own message in javascript. Ex. I'm doing a search with google maps to get geo coordinates, if no coordinates come back I, A.) don't submit B.) I want to use the validationmessagefor to display something like "Search Results Not Found" I thought it would be easier to use the tag because it's already there instead of creating another hidden tag then unhiding it, etc., etc.

Comment: No one can help unless you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, for custom messages coming from server you need to send the object to server and then get the response from it.

You can perform it with an ajax call for example:

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'POST',
        data : results,
        success:function(datafromserver)     
        {                 
 $('.resultState').html(datafromserver);
         }    
});
```

Another thing if do validation first in the client and then send (and check again in server), in this case remember  var result can always be true if the getLocation functions returns anything (such as string , object etc...) so in this case print it with console.log and take a look if is it an object (f example: data.x === none or 'no coordinates' just evaluate it correctly and you can avoid ajax.

Hope helped!
Regards